# Can't connect to Gmail SMTP from Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, email

This is my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myuser@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myuser@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

And @ mail.php I have

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME') 
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD')
```

Error I get: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

I also tried ssl/465 same thing

Credentials are fine and less secure apps enabled, I can connect with them without problem using my own framework + phpmailer class.
I also tried the captcha unlock google's thing.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, somehow the "allow less secure apps" feature got turned of by itself.
Not sure how it's even possible or why I was still able to connect through phpmailer.